# How to divide a heightmap into several layers with ImageMagick?

Tags: image, image-processing, scripting, imagemagick, heightmap

Let's say I have got a grayscale heightmap that has colors ranging from A (rather dark) to B (rather white). The map is not normalized, so the lowest value isn't pitch black and the highest one probably also isn't fully white.
Let's also say 0 means black and 1 means white. What I want to do is to divide the image into several seperate images based on height. Every image has a black background.

This would for example mean:
Image 1 contains all the image content between 0 and 0.2, with anything above that being reduced to 0.2.
Image 2 contains everything between 0.2 and 0.4, everything below 0.2 is black.
Image 3 is the same between 0.4 and 0.6, and all this goes up to 1. You get the idea.

Do you know any way to automate this process with ImageMagick?
If not, is there any other way I could do this?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify. You want everything between 0.2 and 0.4, but everything below 0.4 is black makes no sense. That has nothing to do with the range 0.2 to 0.4 since all becomes black below 0.4. Then what do you want to do with data above 0.4? Do you mean all above 0.4 to be black.  In your first part, you  are filling everything above 0.2 with 0.2 and not black? So where is the black in that layer?

Comment: Everything below 0.2, I meant. Sorry!
Basicly, the background should always be black, and everything between two tresholds should be visible, while everything above the higher treshold should be reduced to that treshold brightness value.

Comment: See my ADDITION in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to slice the image at different heights, then you can do that using a combination of -black-threshold and -white-threshold using percents rather than fractions in ImageMagick. The following will keep each range of gray levels and make the rest black. Black threshold keeps everything above a value and makes the rest black. White threshold keeps everything below a value and makes the rest white. So after the white threshold, we just change white to black.

Unix syntax for IM 6. If using IM 7, change `convert` to `magick`

Input:
(Create a gradient image for demonstration)

```
convert -size 256x256 gradient: grad.png
```

[image]

```
convert grad.png -write mpr:grad +delete \
\( mpr:grad -white-threshold 20% -fill black -opaque white +write t1.png \) \
\( mpr:grad -black-threshold 20% -white-threshold 40% -fill black -opaque white +write t2.png \) \
\( mpr:grad -black-threshold 40% -white-threshold 60% -fill black -opaque white +write t3.png \) \
\( mpr:grad -black-threshold 60% -white-threshold 80% -fill black -opaque white +write t4.png \) \
\( mpr:grad -black-threshold 80% +write t5.png \) \
null:
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**ADDITION**

Based upon your comment, the code should be changed as follows:

```
convert grad.png -write mpr:grad +delete \
\( mpr:grad -white-threshold 20% -fill "gray(20%)" -opaque white +write t1.png \) \
\( mpr:grad -black-threshold 20% -white-threshold 40% -fill "gray(40%)" -opaque white +write t2.png \) \
\( mpr:grad -black-threshold 40% -white-threshold 60% -fill "gray(60%)" -opaque white +write t3.png \) \
\( mpr:grad -black-threshold 60% -white-threshold 80% -fill "gray(80%)" -opaque white +write t4.png \) \
\( mpr:grad -black-threshold 80% +write t5.png \) \
null:
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Can someone translate this into Windows DOS? I am trying, but I haven't suceeded so far.

Comment: For this command in Windows CMD you'll need to: Remove all the backslashes that escape parentheses, so change these "\\( ... \\)" to just these "( ... )". Change the backslashes "\" at the ends of lines to carets "^". And if you're using it in a BAT script, change all the percent signs "%" to double "%%".